# How to Update a Datastore entity using GWT

Tags: entity, google-cloud-datastore, gxt, objectify

I am building a game using google web toolkit.My attempt is to update the score of the player once he win .Scores and the player info are placed in a datastore.I was only able to update the score only once and if the player wins more than once the score is not getting updated.
Here is the code:

```
@Override
  public User updateScore(int newScore,String username) {


    User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(username).get();
            user.setScore(newScore);
            ofy().save().entity(user).now();            
                return user;

    )   
  any idea???
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a transaction. Read this:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts?tm=6#Transactions

While it may or may not affect your subsequent query, you should also be aware of eventual consistency in the datastore:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Answer (score 1):

Transaction as suggested, also check your web.xml file, if it has ObjectifyFilter!

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have managed to solve that problem but got stuck in another one :(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822536/datastore-query-returns-null).  If you have an idea about that and can answer that it would be great.

Comment: Please leave info, what was wrong! Add answer or/and mark right one! Also just for info did you check your web.xml file, if it has ObjectifyFilter?