# Datastore Query returns null

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to retrieve a sorted list of the players scores from a datastore Entity of type"User"
After executing:

```
 List<User> entities = ofy().load().type(User.class).order("-score").list();
```

Knowing that I indexed the "score" attribute.
Here is the "User.class"

```
@Id String userName;
     String password;
    @Index int score;
```

The entities seem to be null and i can't get the entities details.What am I missing???

I am still working on that I managed to modify the method to:

```
 @Override
  public User display(){
     List<User> list = ofy().load().type(User.class).order("-score").limit(5).list();
     User u= list.get(list.size()-1);
      if(!u.getUserName().equals(null))  
        return  u;
      return null;
  }
```

I managed to get rid of the "null" value by checking the username field but the return value was always the first user in the entity no matter how I changed list.get(index).I tried different values for index but always received the first user and can't retrieve the others.
Hoping to get an answer that would solve the problem.

The entities are stored in the database as follows:

```
public User registerAccount(String username, String password,String confirm) {
        User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(username).get();



        if(user == null){
            if(password.contains(" "))          
                return null;            
            if(password.compareTo(confirm)!=0)
                return null;

            else{
            user = new User(username,password,0);
            ofy().save().entity(user).now();
            return user;
            }
         }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
  }
```

So is there any problem in using ofy().save()... rather than datastore.put()...
I am wondering if that would affect that as the score is not found in the datastore indexes.

Comment: Is this local dev server or on a running app?  Did you verify in datastore viewer that the entities you're looking for exist?

Comment: Yes sure the entities exist.I checked the datastore viewer and they exist.But I used ofy().save().entity(user).now(); to save an entity of type User rather than using datastore.put().So do you have an idea if this might affect the query?

Comment: What do you mean "the entities seem to be null"? The list is empty? You're getting a list of nulls back from the query? The entities have null fields?

Comment: @stickfigure Please check my edit.Hope u have an idea of the strange results coming up.

Comment: There still isn't enough information here to understand what is going on. Try to construct a complete test case, including how you save the original data.

Comment: @stickifigure Please check the edit .I included how the entities are stored

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that @Index annotation on "score" property was not there from the beginning. Users that were added before update, can't be fetched by .order("-score") command.

Another possible thing is trivial but common! It is your class naming ("User"). Do you have correct import? GAE also has quite common class com.google.appengine.api.users.User that is used for authentication.

Comment: I added the index abbotation before storing the entities but for some reason when checking the appengine The datastore index is empty "You have not created indexes for this application."So shouldn't the score property be added to the datastore-index.

Comment: "You have not created indexes for this application." message is OK in GAE admin console! When you use @Index annotation it will not show new index in Datastore Indexes link. You can check, if there is index on local instance of GAE (http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/). Select to view entity items, than you can see in table of records, if it is indexed or not. Every record field value, that is not indexed has label (unindexed).

Comment: I already checked that the scire property doesn't have the unindexed label that what confused me since I couldn't find it stored in datastore indexes.

Comment: so if it the score is indexed how can I get the sorted list of entities by score??

Comment: Your command statement looks good too me. List<User> entities = ofy().load().type(User.class).order("score").list(); Try 1.List<User> entities = ofy().load().type(User.class).list(); 2. List<User> entities = ofy().load().type(User.class).order("score").list(); 3. List<User> entities = ofy().load().type(User.class).order("-score").list();

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities listed but I coult get the list as expected to be when running this method I got an error in connecting to the server I suppose that I have to check for a certain condition such as if username not null or so similar to the register account method but don't know what can I check to get a valid list of users